# An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the following code:

```
System.Drawing.Image originalImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

The image you opened is too large for your app (prob. 32bit) to handle.

Comment: Thanks Lee337 for reply.
This error occur when I try to upload more than 4 MB jpg file and I want to upload a large file.